# Does a Search engine rate the alt attribute on image tags?

Tags: search, search-engine, seo

Do search engines rate also the alt atribute in image tags? 
In my opinion the alt attribute was for blind peoples.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate...

Comment: Ok if it is, then you are welcome to delete it. Or should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search led me to this blog post:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/12/using-alt-attributes-smartly.html

It seems at least google is checking the alt attribute but every search engine has it's own methods so [your favourite search engine] might not use it.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I can think of.

1. It is for "visually impaired" people , improving accessibility of your site.

2. If the download speed is not good, like Jonathan Sampson puts it, it is quite useful to users to get a glance of the image.

3. It also **helpful** to image search, but I am not sure about it.

All in all, `atl`  attribute is helpful to users. TAO that end, I believe most of search engines will give weight to that attribute.

Mind you though, just inter concise description text, otherwise, it is even harmful to your SEO.

Answer (score 0):

The `alt` attribute isn't just for blind people, it shows up when the image itself doesn't load still informing the visually-able to understand what was supposed to be there. As for the search engines, I don't think there's any solid resource telling you the specifics of each.

In my opinion, you should continue to use it as a good practice and for the potential that this information is used in image-search engines. After all, searching for "Jonathan Sampson" should turn up images that have an alt text of "Photo of Jonathan Sampson."

Comment: Thank i will set on all images an alt atribute as good practice for me,for searchengines and for the blind people

Comment: It was also great for use with Lynx http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)

Comment: Yes thats true, lynx is something very special in case if you dont have X in your Linux box ;-)

Comment: @Matthew Whited: I doubt Lynx is really a target browser for any commercial/professional web site. It is ok for testing your website for accessibility (for which i would recommend it to the OP) but it's useless for anything other than to browse kernel.org. Anyways, you should at least use links.

Comment: Never said it was... also havn't used it in the better part of 5 years... I just said it worked well with 'alt' tags